# How will you loop the fadeIn animation?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery.

I want this animation to play continuously. It plays only once and stops.  sorry placed wrong code. it should be like below

**HTML**

```
<div id="imageslide">
    <ul id="carousel">
        <li><img src="img/apart1.png" alt="Excellent Apartment"></li>
        <li><img src="img/apart2.png" alt="Beautiful Apartment"></li>
        <li><img src="img/apart3.png" alt="Brilliant Apartment"></li>
        <li><img src="img/apart4.png" alt="Nice Apartment"></li>
        <li id="last"><img src="img/apart5.png" alt="Marvellous Apartment"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").slice(1).addClass("hide");

    function anim(elm) { 
        elm.delay(1500).fadeIn(1500, function() { 
            anim($(this).next());
        });  
    }

    anim($("#carousel li:first"));

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the rest of the code ? elm() is not a funciton, fadeLI() is not a function

Comment: Will there be a dynamic number of images or will it **always** be 5?

Comment: sorry for that....please check the code now. the images are dynamic number

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = $('li img').length;

    function showNext(target_num)
    {
        var currImg = target_num;
        var nextImg = (target_num === (images-1) ? 0 : target_num+=1);

        $('li img').eq(currImg).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('li img').eq(nextImg).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                showNext(nextImg);
            });
        });
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        showNext(0);
    }, 1000);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="imageslide">
    <ul id="carousel">
        <li>
            <img src="img/apart1.png" alt="Excellent Apartment">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/apart2.png" alt="Beautiful Apartment" style="display:none;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/apart3.png" alt="Brilliant Apartment" style="display:none;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/apart4.png" alt="Nice Apartment" style="display:none;">
        </li>
        <li id="last">    
            <img src="img/apart5.png" alt="Marvellous Apartment" style="display:none;">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDNLc/1/)**

Comment: You're welcome, if you found this answer to be truly sufficient please go ahead and mark it as `Accepted`